# Is the boundary of a boundary a subset of the boundary?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of a boundary of a set $S$ in a topological space $X$ is $\text{comp}\{\text{Int}(S) \cup \text{Ext}(S)\}$ (complement of the interior union exterior).

The definition for interior is the set of all interior points.

The definition for interior point of $S$ is if there exists an open neighborhood $N$ of that point such that $N \subset S$.

The definition of neighborhood of a point $x$ is a subset of the topological space $X$ that contains an open set such that $x$ is in that open set.

The definition for exterior of $S$ is $\text{Int}(\text{Comp}(S))$.

So $\text{Bdry}(\text{Bdry}(S)) = \text{comp}\{\text{Int}(\text{comp}\{\text{Int}(S) \cup \text{Ext}(S)\}) \cup \text{Ext}(\text{comp}\{\text{Int}(S) \cup \text{Ext}(S)\})\}$ which I can't make heads or tails of. Is there an easier approach to checking of the boundary of the boundary is a subset of the boundary using these definitions?

Comment: I think you need to know something about the topology to say anything interesting about the boundary of the boundary.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443404/boundary-of-the-boundary-of-a-set-is-empty

Comment: A cheap answer,I know,but I found it useful and so will you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ be a space, and let $A\subseteq X$. Then $\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A$, so $\operatorname{bdry}A$ is a closed set. Thus,

$$\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{bdry}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{bdry}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}\operatorname{bdry}A\subseteq\operatorname{bdry}A\;.$$

That is, the boundary of the boundary of $A$ is always a subset of the boundary of $A$.

It’s also true, by the way, that

$$\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{bdry}A=\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{bdry}A\;;$$

you’ll find a sketch of the proof in the first part of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200413/basic-problem-on-topology-james-dugundji).

Comment: How do you know that $\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A$?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: That’s a standard equivalence; some people take it as the definition, in fact. The definition that you’re using reduces immediately to $$(X\setminus\operatorname{ext}A) \cap (X\setminus\operatorname{int}A) = (\operatorname{cl}A)\cap(X\setminus\operatorname{int}A) = (\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A\;.$$

Comment: I now have trouble seeing why $X - \operatorname{ext}A=\operatorname{cl}A$. Our definition of the closure of a set $A$ is the intersection of all the closed subsets of the topological space $X$ which contain $A$ as a subset.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Then your first step should probably be to prove the fundamental fact that $\operatorname{cl}A$ is also the set of points $x$ such that every open nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$. There are times (and this is one of them) when this equivalent characterization of $\operatorname{cl}A$ is by far the easiest to use.

Comment: Is $(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A$ a closed set because any closed set with its interior removed is closed?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: It’s more general than that: if $F$ is closed, and $U$ is open, then $F\setminus U=F\cap(X\setminus U)$ is the intersection of two closed sets and is therefore closed.

Comment: Okay, so I see now that $\mathrm{Cl}(A)$ is the set of points such that every neighborhood of every point intersects $A$. How can I use this result to show that $\mathrm{Cl}(A) = X - \mathrm{Ext}(A)$ if $\mathrm{Ext}(A) = \mathrm{Int}(\mathrm{Comp}(A))$?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Have you tried? I ask because that’s a very easy proof.

Comment: Well, I don't see any immediate relationship between every neighborhood of points in the closure intersecting with $A$, and the exterior of $A$. So using the definitions, I have to show that $\mathrm{Cl}(A) \subset X - \mathrm{Ext}(A)$, and vice versa. So for one direction, assume $x \in \mathrm{Cl}(A)$. Then we have to show $x \in X - Int(Comp(A))$. So this is a closed set, and if I can prove that $A \subset X - Int(Comp(A))$ then I think $X - Int(Comp(A))$ also contains $Cl(A)$. But not sure how to prove that part. For the other direction, I run into a similarly circular issue.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Let $U=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$. Clearly $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ is an open subset of $X\setminus A$, so $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq U$. On the other hand, if $x\in U$, then $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$, so $x\notin\operatorname{cl}A$, and therefore $U\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A=U$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought we were trying to prove $X - U = Cl(A)$ (since it looks like $U$ in your proof is $Ext(A)$. I am a bit confused.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: Yes, $U$ is $\operatorname{ext}A$. Proving that $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A=U$ immediately proves that $X\setminus U=\operatorname{cl}A$: just take complements on both sides. This really should not cause you more than a moment’s hesitation.

Comment: In general, are we allowed to just add/subtract sets from both sides of an equation involving sets?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs: If two things are equal, and you perform the same operation on both of them, the resulting objects will still be equal.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary of $S$ is closed in $X$, because it is the intersection of two closed subsets: $$\overline{S} \cap (X \backslash \mathrm{Int}(S)).$$ Therefore, it contains its own boundary.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Boundary_of_Boundary_is_Contained_in_Boundary

Answer (score 1):

Yes; using your definition, the question you need to answer is:

> Can the boundary of the boundary of $S$ intersect $\text{Int}(S)$ or $\text{Ext}(S)$?

because if the answer is "no", then it *must* be a subset of the boundary, as the only points not contained in the boundary are those in the interior or exterior.

To sketch part of a proof, notice that the $U=\text{Int}(S)\cup\text{Ext}(S)$ is an open set and is, by definition, disjoint from the boundary. In particular, this means it is in the complement of the boundary *and is open*, implying that every point contained therein, having $U$ as a neighborhood, is in the exterior of the boundary. $U$ is therefore disjoint from in the boundary of the boundary, which implies that the boundary of the boundary is a subset of the boundary.

Comment: I don't understand why the question boils down to the boundary of the boundary of $S$ intersecting $\text{Int}(S)$ or $\text{Ext}(S)$

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs $\text{Int}(S)\cup \text{Ext}(S)$ is the complement of the boundary; saying $A$ is a subset of $B$ is equivalent to saying a set $A$ doesn't intersect that complement of $B$.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading this over and I understand that $U$ is disjoint from the boundary, but I don't understand why $U$ is disjoint from the boundary of the boundary. Is it because the boundary of boundary is a closed set? If so, isn't it possible that an open set contains a closed set? I can't visualize the boundary of a boundary, so all I can tell is that it's a closed set that may or may not be in $U$, and we want to prove that it's not in $U$, but I can't see how a set being the exterior of a boundary implies that the exterior is disjoint from the boundary of the boundary

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs The point is that the exterior of the boundary contains (and, in fact, equals) $U$. From definition, $U$ is the complement of the boundary. So, the interior of $U$ is the interior of the complement (i.e. the exterior) of the boundary - but if $U$ is open, then $\text{int}(U)=U$, as each point has $U\subseteq U$ as an open neighborhood. Thus, $U$ is the exterior of the boundary - and the boundary of the boundary must be disjoint from the exterior of the boundary (being the complement of the union of the exterior and interior of the boundary)

Comment: Intuitively thinking about the boundary of the boundary, if I take the complement of the exterior (which is denoted by $U$ here), then obviously it's disjoint from $U$, but if I take the complement of the interior of the boundary (which is disjoint from $U$), then taking the complement of something disjoint from $U$ feels like it would bring us back into $U$ somehow, so taking the union of these feels like it won't be disjoint from $U$.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs The important bit is that we take the complement *after* the union. If we let $I$ be the interior of the boundary, then the boundary of the boundary is $(U\cup I)^C$ - which is a set disjoint from $U\cup I$. Since $U$ is a subset of $U\cup I$, it follows that any set disjoint from $U\cup I$ is disjoint from $U$ too - and as such, the boundary is.

Comment: Okay, I see exactly where I am having trouble now. I know the boundary is disjoint from $U$, but it seems like a contradiction because I thought the interior of the boundary was a subset of the boundary, so the boundary can't be totally disjoint from $U \cup I$ since the interior of the boundary is in there.